# Php/Wordpress: Storing post content into variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

When using the the_post() loop, how do I fetch the post data?
I can't retrieve the post content data with the_content() because it automatically 'prints' the content on the screen.

I need it to be stored in a value so I can manipulate it, I need to display only a small portion of the content for the headlines.

Comment: Have you searched the Wordpress API (the Codex)?

Comment: General tip: if you have a wordpress function `the_x()` that ouputs something, then there's usually a `get_the_x()` that returns that output instead of outputting it.

Answer (score 10):

use `get_the_content()` to get the contents of the post

Answer (score 3):

See `get_the_content()` function - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Note the section there on applying filters `apply_filters('the_content',...`

Answer (score -1):

Or... just the global var $post

```
$post->post_content
```